# Alternative to bluetooth beacons

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm not too sure if this is the best place to ask this question, but I don't know who else to ask so.

I've been working on an app to help my school track attendance for students. They currently do it by passing a piece of paper around the class which is not great during these covid times.

My current solution involves implementing a bluetooth beacon in each classroom to check if the student is physically present in the class.

The problem is that these beacons are expensive and doesn't allow me to give my solution to my school for free. I also have to wait for beacons to be shipped in.

Does anyone here know of any alternatives to using beacons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Bluetooth beacon to check attendance usually requires that each student have a Bluetooth LE capable smartphone with network access and a custom app installed to report seeing the beacon to a server.

It is possible to use another Bluetooth LE capable smartphone to transmit the beacon signal.  An app on the teacher's phone might do this.

Alternately, you can reverse the process and have each student's phone transmit a beacon advertisement with a unique identifier per student and have the teacher phone count them all.  This alternative eliminates the need for a server or network access.

Both if these solutions require that everybody have a Bluetooth LE capable smartphone with a custom app installed.

Comment: I thought of having the teachers device as a beacon and like the idea a lot but the problem is the range. It won’t be feasible in a larger classroom.

Comment: I don't think that is true.  Unless the classroom is a stadium seating many thousands, this won't be an issue.  A BLE transmitter at maximum power with clear line of sight will have a reliable range of 30 meters, and an intermittent range of over 50 meters.  So even in the case of a football stadium, this could still work if the teacher is in the middle of the field.   A single transmitter placed dead center in the middle of the football stadium will intermittently be detectable by tens of thousands of fans seated anywhere, provided that the fans hold up their phones briefly for reception.

Comment: That's pretty cool I didn't know that. I'll try it out and see how it goes. I do think that each teacher's device will have a different range though.